# Как добавить числовое увеличивающиеся значение в цикле foreach?

Tags: php

К значению переменной `$name` необходимо добавить числовое значение.

```
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    if (count($key_val) == 2) {
     $html .= (($_ptype != "wccaf") ? '<li>' : '') . '<input type="radio" id="' .$name. '" />' . (($_ptype != "wccaf") ? '</li>' : '');
    }
}
```

На выходе значение должно выглядеть так:
имя-1
имя-2
имя-3

Comment: И что мешает создать переменную перед циклом и инкрементировать её внутри цикла?

Comment: Спасибо, это и было моей ошибкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте переменную счетчика

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    $counter++;
    $name = 'имя-' . $counter;
}
```